# undefined reference to operator delete in destructor of istringstream from libc++

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, clang++

I tried to build `clang++` from trunk (~3.7) in a two ways: by means of `gcc` (4.8) and by means of (old) `clang++` (3.4 and 3.5 from packet manager). Both of them consists of the same steps:

```
export CC=clang
export CXX=clang++
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH="$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH:$HOME/llvm/projects/libcxxabi/include"

sudo apt-get install git

cd
git clone --single-branch --branch master --depth=1 http://llvm.org/git/llvm
cd llvm/projects/
git clone --single-branch --branch master --depth=1 http://llvm.org/git/libcxxabi
git clone --single-branch --branch master --depth=1 http://llvm.org/git/libcxx
git clone --single-branch --branch master --depth=1 http://llvm.org/git/compiler-rt
cd ../tools
git clone --single-branch --branch master --depth=1 http://llvm.org/git/clang
git clone --single-branch --branch master --depth=1 http://llvm.org/git/clang-tools-extra extra
git clone --single-branch --branch master --depth=1 http://llvm.org/git/lld
git clone --single-branch --branch master --depth=1 http://llvm.org/git/lldb
git clone --single-branch --branch master --depth=1 http://llvm.org/git/polly

sudo apt-get install python-dev libedit-dev libncurses-dev swig libgmp-dev libgmp3-dev dh-autoreconf libunwind8 libunwind8-dev cmake

cd
cd llvm/tools/polly/utils
mkdir -p ~/build-cloog
bash checkout_cloog.sh ~/build-cloog
mkdir -p ~/build-isl
bash checkout_isl.sh ~/build-isl
cd ~/build-isl/
./configure
make
sudo make install
cd ~/build-cloog/
./configure --with-isl=system
make
sudo make install

cd
mkdir build-llvm
cd build-llvm
bash ../llvm/configure --enable-optimized --disable-assertions --enable-libcpp --enable-jit --enable-targets=x86,x86_64 --enable-polly --enable-cxx1y --with-gmp=/usr/local --with-isl=/usr/local --with-cloog=/usr/local --with-binutils-include=/usr/include
make -j`nproc`
sudo make install
```

For `CC=clang` and `CXX=clang++` I got error during linking of simple example containing `std::istringstream` instantiation:

```
#include <sstream>

#include <cstdlib>

int
main()
{
        std::istringstream iss("1.1");
        double x;
        iss >> x;
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The error:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=gnu++1z -Ofast -march=native test.cpp -o /tmp/test
/tmp/test-785a74.o: In function `std::__1::basic_istringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_istringstream()':
test.cpp:(.text._ZNSt3__119basic_istringstreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEED0Ev[_ZNSt3__119basic_istringstreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEED0Ev]+0x5b): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
/tmp/test-785a74.o: In function `virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_istringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_istringstream()':
test.cpp:(.text._ZTv0_n24_NSt3__119basic_istringstreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEED0Ev[_ZTv0_n24_NSt3__119basic_istringstreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEED0Ev]+0x69): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
/tmp/test-785a74.o: In function `std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringbuf()':
test.cpp:(.text._ZNSt3__115basic_stringbufIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEED0Ev[_ZNSt3__115basic_stringbufIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEED0Ev]+0x26): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

But the error does not occur, if `CC=gcc` and `CXX=g++`. The linker is `ld` from `GNU Binutils` in both cases.

Exampli gratia for objects from `#include <iostream>` there is no such problem.

What is the cause of the error? Can I fix it without rebuilding the whole `clang/llvm` project tree?

Comment: how do you compile (link!) the example?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I type the command `clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=gnu++1z -Ofast -march=native test.cpp -o /tmp/test`

Comment: There is exactly the same problem for `std::ifstream`.

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu 14.10 with clang 3.7 trunk + libc++ coming from the packet manager. Are you sure clang is including libc++ headers and not libstdc++ ones? Check with '-v' - should show something like `/usr/include/c++/v1`.

Comment: @Thomas My `clang` gives `/usr/local/bin/../include/c++/v1`, when `echo "#include <cxxabi.h>" | clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=gnu++1z -Wp,-v -x c++ - -fsyntax-only` typed. Do you mean, that *Ubuntu 14.10* already providing `clang v3.7` or instead: you build the `clang 3.7` from trunk by means of `clang 3.7` from packet manager and it works fine?

Comment: @Orient: No, I have built clang 3.7 from the SVN sources, but I am using `libc++` coming from the packet manager. Are you sure you really need such a recent `clang` + `libc++` version? You might better stick to 3.6 which will be released soon. http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/branches

Comment: @Thomas I do not remeber why compiled with the latest version of `libc++` (seems it was `std::begin`/`std::end` presence). There no 3.6 version at the moment, so my choise remains the same.

Comment: @Orient: There is a 3.6 branch http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/branches/ + http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxxabi/branches/.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There was a recent change in clang trunk. The compiler does no longer emit weak definitions of the sized operator delete (see the [commit 229241](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=229241)). The flag to emit the definitions anyway (`-fdef-sized-delete`) was renamed later in [commit 229597](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=229597).

You have to compile your program with the `-fdefine-sized-deallocation` flag so that clang emits the sized operator delete. This should fix your link error.

Comment: Ugh, I am actually hitting this too with gcc libstdc++ 4.9. I really hope they will revert this change,
or at least make `-fdef-sized-delete` the default. Otherwise anyone with a not so recent libc++/libstdc++ will run into linker errors...

Comment: Thank you. Is it a defect of `libc++` library design?

Comment: @Orient: Maybe it would help to use the very latest `libc++` to get rid of the linker errors without `-fdef-sized-delete`. See: https://github.com/chapuni/libcxx/commit/19efe01. However, this totally breaks `libstdc++` <= `4.9` and any non recent `libc++` version. I **really** hope they will revert this, otherwise this will end in a horrible mess. For example it's not easy to upgrade `libc++/libstdc++` on OS X. This would also break `clang's` explicit support for old `libstdc++` versions.

Comment: The flag just got renamed: http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=229597.

Comment: There is also a short explanation on the C++ status page of clang: http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#n3778